# Fixedpoints examples in z3-4.0 do not work because of missing buddy/fdd.h and buddy/bdd.h

Tags: z3

I want to try the example in fixedpoints of z3 (path Z3-4.0/examples/fixedpoints), but the source files are not compilable because of missing buddy/fdd.h and buddy/bdd.h (defined in bdd_table.h). Could you guys please tell me where I can find these files?. Thank

Answer (score 1):

Yes, BuDDy is not developed by us.
It was created by Jorn Lind.
You can download BuDDy from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/buddy/